# Force Flutter DataTable to use Available space for rows before scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to preview the row data of 3 columns in a csv.

The columns are name, location, consent_prompt. I have gotten the data, the only issue is that if the name is too long, the table doesn't wrap the text appropriately, instead the columns are shifted out of view port, as a result I had to use a SingleChildScrollView in Axis.horizontal direction to scroll them into view which is not a very good UI.

Is there no way to force the datable to show all 3 columns without the user scrolling left and right to see them?

Here is my current setup:

```
  _buildPreview() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: DataTable(
            columns:
                _csvColumns.map((e) => DataColumn(label: Text(e))).toList(),
            rows: _csvRowData.map((row) {
              return DataRow(
                cells:
                    row.values.map((data) => DataCell(Text('$data'))).toList(),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```